# Performance problems on desktop using KDE Plasma (FerenOS)

Tags: drivers, kde, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

I recently installed FerenOS on my PC because I really like the KDE Plasma Desktop Environment. I'm using an Nvidia GTX 1070ti with 460-drivers (proprietary).

I experience audio and video lags especially on my desktop when windows or notifications open.

**What I tried in order to fix this:**

- disabling compositor -> works, but not an option
- enabling "Force Full Composition Pipeline" in NVIDIA X Server Settings -> worked until reboot
- adding Tearing.sh file to /etc/profile.d/ with following content:

```
export __GL_YIELD="USLEEP"

export __GL_THREADED_OPTIMIZATIONS=1
```

I successfully removed tearing with those tweaks, but I still have those performance issues which I can't live with. I also don't have any ideas left what the possible reason is...
I've been googling for days now and tried everything I found, but I can't solve this problem. :(

**My specs:**

- AMD Ryzen 5 1600
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070ti with proprietary drivers
- 16GB RAM
- 2 SSDs (1 Windows 10, 1 FerenOS)
- Multiple HDDs
- Dual monitor setup with different refresh rates and resolutions
- Multiple audio devices (USB headset, AUX soundbar)

If any other information is needed please let me know, I am greatly thankful for any help I can possibly get.